# Loop breaks over an array when a condition is met with google apps script

Tags: javascript, arrays, google-apps-script

I have an array and I am trying to identify a particular text in every element and remove only if that element from the array where there is a match.

the array is

```
var Concat_names = ['Prod 1-Volume based deal-100 sections','Test Prod 1-Included Members-MB,'Prod 2-Commitment + Excess-100 sections','Prod 1-Flat Mon-TB'];
```

1. If any element in the array has `Flat Mon` then remove that element from array
2. If any element in the array has `Included Members` then remove that element from array

The below is what I tried-

```
for (var i in Concat_names) {
    var check_included_mem = Concat_names[i].includes("Included Members");
    if (check_included_mem == true) {
      Concat_names.splice(i);
    }
  }
  console.log(Concat_names);

for (var y in Concat_names){
    var check_flat_mon = new RegExp(/Flat Mon/).test(Concat_names[y]); 
    if (check_flat_mon==true){
      Concat_names.splice(y);
    }
  }
  console.log(Concat_names);
```

With the above code, the loop is breaking out whenever the condition is met and missing out on other elements in the array.

The output I am getting is

```
[ 'Prod 1-Volume based deal-100 sections' ]
```

whereas the output should be

```
['Prod 1-Volume based deal-100 sections','Prod 2-Commitment + Excess-100 sections']
```

Please guide and help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your script, how about the following modification?

#### From:

```
Concat_names.splice(i);
```

#### To:

```
Concat_names.splice(i, 1);
```

In this case, please modify both `Concat_names.splice(i);` to `Concat_names.splice(i, 1);`.

#### Testing:

```js
var Concat_names = ['Prod 1-Volume based deal-100 sections', 'Test Prod 1-Included Members-MB', 'Prod 2 - Commitment + Excess - 100 sections', 'Prod 1 - Flat Mon - TB'];

for (var i in Concat_names) {
  var check_included_mem = Concat_names[i].includes("Included Members");
  if (check_included_mem == true) {
    Concat_names.splice(i, 1);
  }
}
console.log(Concat_names);
for (var y in Concat_names) {
  var check_flat_mon = new RegExp(/Flat Mon/).test(Concat_names[y]);
  if (check_flat_mon == true) {
    Concat_names.splice(y, 1);
  }
}
console.log(Concat_names);
```

#### Note:

- In your situation, the following script might be able to be also used.

```js
var Concat_names = ['Prod 1-Volume based deal-100 sections', 'Test Prod 1-Included Members-MB', 'Prod 2 - Commitment + Excess - 100 sections', 'Prod 1 - Flat Mon - TB'];
var res = Concat_names.filter(e => !["Included Members", "Flat Mon"].some(f => e.includes(f)));
console.log(res)
```

#### Reference:

- [splice()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice)

Comment: Thank you as always @ Tanaike -san, owe you a big one, I missed the  hoe many elements to remove parameter.

Comment: @Alicia Stone Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. Thank you, too.